# Creating a database column based on an existing column

Tags: r, function, stocks

I have to calculate the Monthly Return for some businesses using this function:

monthly return for month i+1 = (closing price in month i+1 - closing price in month i)/closing price in month i

I have a data set that contains the closing price every month for about 10 year. How would I create/use a function to calculate the MR for each month?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
monthly <- c(100, 120, 130, 100, 140)  # replace this of course with actual data

result <- rep(NA, length(monthly))
for (i in 1:(length(monthly)-1)) {
   result[i+1] <- (monthly[i+1] - monthly[i]) / monthly[i] 
}
```

`result` will now contain your answer. Note that the first position will contain an `NA`, since you are not interested in month `i` being 1.

Comment: ahhh okay thanks that makes a lot of sense. I was trying to do something like that but tried to make it 1:length(monthly). Thanks!